# Не отправляет файл json на клиент

Tags: node.js

использую эту строку app.use(body_parser.json()) , я не могу выполнить этот блок. Идет долго  загрузка страницы и не выводит никаких данных.

```
app.get("/get", function (req,res,next) {
console.log("Open");
 res.json(connectResult);
next();
});
```

Если убрать эту строку,данные с сервера приходят,на клиенте выводит информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас ошибка, Вы видимо хотели написать app.use(body_parser.json()).

Comment: Точно,заработало.!